# Handler sending message to a Handler on a dead thread although thread is alive in openCamera()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-handler

I am using a custom background handler to call the `CameraManager.openCamera()` method.

Although I have a check and a log stating that `backgroundHandler?.looper?.thread?.isAlive` and the thread is instanced and it is the thread I want to use, the camera previews gets stuck and I get a crash in the logs stating: `Handler (android.os.Handler) {9360be3} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread`.

The issue happens only when using the recent apps button 2 times very fast (exiting the app and entering again very fast).